# ¿Se destruyen los miembros de un std::vector al destruir la clase que lo contiene?

Tags: c++

soy un aficionado con cierta experiencia en programar con un lenguaje muy parecido a C y estoy reciclándome hacia el uso de C++. Estoy estudiando el funcionamiento de los punteros inteligentes y vectores, que es algo totalmente nuevo para mí. Creo entender el funcionamiento pero no alcanzo a encontrar la respuesta a la pregunta del título y me asalta mi propia inseguridad.

Supongamos que tengo una clase con un vector de objetos de otra clase que dimensiono en el constructor de la clase.

```
class MySubClass
{
   MySubClass() = default;
   ~MySubClass() = default;
}

class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass() { m_vector.resize(512); }
   ~MyClass() = default;
private:
   std::vector<MySubClass> m_vector;
}
```

Si dentro de alguna función creo un nuevo objeto 'MyClass' con 'new', y lo elimino con 'delete', entiendo que el destructor de la clase llamará al destructor del vector, que llamará al destructor de los objetos contenidos en el vector. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? o ¿tengo que llamar a 'm_vector.clear' o 'm_vector.erase' dentro del destructor de la clase para que se libere la memoria utilizada por los objetos contenidos en el vector?

Creo entender que si en vez de crear el objeto lo declaro y defino dentro del scope de una función, el comportamiento será el mismo al terminar la función, por lo que me asalta la misma duda.

Entiendo que si el vector es de punteros habrá que utilizar punteros inteligentes para que el vector reconozca la propiedad de los objetos.

Disculpad tan básica pregunta. Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nada mejor como verlo en funcionamiento con un ejemplo práctico.

Lo primero es tener una clase que haga de Conejillo de Indias

```
class POO
{
  int n_;
public:
  POO(int n)
    : n_{n}
  { std::cout << "POO::POO() - " << n_ << '\n'; }

  POO(POO && other)
    : n_{other.n_}
  { std::cout << "POO::POO(POO&&) - " << n_ << '\n'; }

  ~POO()
  { std::cout << "POO::~POO() - " << n_ << '\n'; }
};
```

Vamos a probar a rellenar el vector por valor:

```
void func()
{
  std::vector<POO> vector;
  vector.reserve(3);
  vector.emplace_back(1);
  vector.emplace_back(2);
  vector.emplace_back(3);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "llamamos a func()\n";
  func();
  std::cout << "salimos de func()\n";
}
```

Este programa arroja la [siguiente salida](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HcQQQoxKTkLfVvnk):

```
llamamos a func()
POO::POO() - 1
POO::POO() - 2
POO::POO() - 3
POO::~POO() - 1
POO::~POO() - 2
POO::~POO() - 3
salimos de func()
```

Aquí vemos cómo se crean 3 objetos POO, los cuales se destruyen justo al salir de la función que contiene el vector.

Luego sí, podemos afirmar que los objetos contenidos en un vector se destruyen cuando finaliza la vida del vector.

**¿Qué sucederá con los punteros?** Veamos:

```
void func()
{
  std::vector<POO*> vector;
  vector.reserve(3);
  vector.emplace_back(new POO(1));
  vector.emplace_back(new POO(2));
  vector.emplace_back(new POO(3));
}
```

La salida ahora será la [siguiente](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WFP2KR7fGZCdCgcH):

```
llamamos a func()
POO::POO() - 1
POO::POO() - 2
POO::POO() - 3
salimos de func()
```

¿Qué ha pasado ahora?

Lo que sucede es que el vector **no libera** la memoria asociada a los punteros. Simple y llanamente.

**¿Y no se puede hacer nada para que la memoria dinámica se libere automáticamente?**

Sí que se puede, basta con usar smart pointers:

```
void func()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<POO>> vector;
  vector.reserve(3);
  vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<POO>(1));
  vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<POO>(2));
  vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<POO>(3));
}
```

Como podemos comprobar, ahora la [salida](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4i9Yu2rQO2ZtMsoF) vuelve a ser la esperada:

```
llamamos a func()
POO::POO() - 1
POO::POO() - 2
POO::POO() - 3
POO::~POO() - 1
POO::~POO() - 2
POO::~POO() - 3
salimos de func()
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Muy esclarecedor.

Answer (score 3):

Es muy fácil de ver con una sencilla modificación de tu ejemplo:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    ~Test( ) { std::cout << "Destructor\n"; }
};

struct MyClass
{
  MyClass( ) { m_vector.emplace_back( ); }
  ~MyClass( ) = default;
private:
   std::vector<Test> m_vector;
};

int main( ) {
  MyClass *mcptr = new MyClass( );
  MyClass mc;
  delete mcptr;

  return 0;
}
```

Y la salida es ...(*redoble de tambores*):

> Destructor
>   Destructor

Por lo tanto, a tus preguntas:

> ...entiendo que el destructor de la clase llamará al destructor del vector, que llamará al destructor de los objetos contenidos en el vector. ¿Estoy en lo cierto?

Totalmente **correcto**.

> ¿tengo que llamar a 'm_vector.clear' o 'm_vector.erase' dentro del destructor de la clase para que se libere la memoria utilizada por los objetos contenidos en el vector?

Ya hemos visto que no, que dicha destrucción es **automática**.

> Creo entender que si en vez de crear el objeto lo declaro y defino dentro del scope de una función, el comportamiento será el mismo al terminar la función, por lo que me asalta la misma duda.

El comportamiento es **exactamente el mismo**. La cuestión es **llamar al destructor**. El como lo hagas, con `delete` o al salir del ámbido, es indifirente.

> Entiendo que si el vector es de punteros habrá que utilizar punteros inteligentes para que el vector reconozca la propiedad de los objetos.

**Totalmente correcto**. El destructor de `std::vector< >` llama al destructor de la clase contenida, y los punteros *pelaos* no incluyen ninguna funcionalidad en su destructor. Tienes que usar *punteros inteligentes* u algún otro método.

Comment: Me olía que había alguien más luchando por ser el primero jejeje

Comment: @eferion XDDD Normal. Para una pregunta *respondible* que aparece ... casi a los puños que llegamos :-)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Muy esclarecedor.